IDLE/Tkinter Error: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in \<module\>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1617, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

When i used idle command for writing python in idle, i got this system message. I don't know what's that mean. I'm so new for ubuntu. I hope someone know this answer.

Does this answer your question? TkInter error: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

This is a tkinter on linux error.  I don't know if answers to the earlier question about the exact same error message will help you.  Perhaps you do not have tcl/tk loaded on your system.

Do your ubuntu have a desktop environment? Did you access the system via SSH?
